# android XML layout not working as expected with tablelayout and scrollview

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, tablelayout

**EDIT:
Does TableLayout not work properly?  I see most of you say use relative layout, and skip tableview?**

[image]

The SPACE on after Data 1 and Data 2 I was trying to get rid of.  If I put the same XML code without the TableLayout then it looks to be ok. What do I change?

The 3rd row with the "100" I wanted 2 entry textviews on the right side. I have tried everything I can think of and it will not go to the right.  I removed the 2nd textview to see if that helped, but didnt make much difference.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?  thank you!

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:padding="6px">

        <TableRow style="@style/FormRows" android:layout_marginTop="15sp">
            <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
                android:layout_span="3" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Save"
                android:id="@+id/dgSave" />
        </TableRow>



        <TableRow style="@style/FormRows">

            <TextView android:layout_width="70sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Data 1" />

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/dgData0" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>



        <TableRow>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:text="100" android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:numeric="integer"
                    android:width="100sp" android:id="@+id/dgWarn0" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_span="2" />


                <EditText android:text="100" android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:numeric="integer"
                    android:width="100sp" android:id="@+id/dgWarn1" android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_span="2" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow style="@style/FormRows">

            <TextView android:layout_width="70sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Data 2" />

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/dgData1" android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

THANK YOU! for any help!!!
Mark

Comment: You should use Table Layout? B'coz we can bring this layout by using Relative Layout.

Comment: I thought the space after Data is because of `android:layout_weight="1"`, but you said you were ok with this xml w/o `TableLayout`...

Comment: I'm not sure why, probably because I just found myself learning LinearLayout and RelativeLayout and re-using them over and over, but I haven't ever used Table Layout... never had a use for it. This would be VERY easy with a Relative Layout. Get the Save button where you want it on top, align the Spinners right edges with the save button's right edge, put the Data labels to the right of the Spinners, etc... should be a snap.

Comment: You should check out Googles Tutorial and see how they used the TableLayout: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: Could you please share a mockup of your desired layout? @Venkatesh mentioned solving the issue using `RelativeLayout`. I totally agree with that, it's far more handy for such complex views. `TableLayout` was created for tables (...) anyway, with `RelativeLayout` you could save the number of layouts as well, so it would be your best choice.

Comment: `TableLayout` would be wasteful when creating such a complex layout. That's why a lot of us suggest you to use `RelativeLayout`. Also, with it your list of options on customizing your view is far more wide! If you would provide an image of your desired layout, any of us would be happy to help you out with a proper RelativeLayout implementation with explanations, which would point you into the right direction. [This is a good starting point](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) from Romain Guy (there are about 4 tricks, you will find them very helpful!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what a RelativeLayout might look like. I did this kind of quickly... it's missing some other margins, etc... but it's a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Save" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/save" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/spinner1"
        android:text="Data 1" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/save"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner1" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/save"
        android:layout_below="@id/editbox" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/spinner2"
        android:text="Data 2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is TableLayout is efficient when compared to Relative Layout?

Comment: I'm not aware of any efficiency difference... but with only a handful of views involved I can't imagine it could make a big difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
I took a quick look in this and maybe TableLayout is now the best choice for this specific activity.
Have you considered using RelativeLayout? There you can define the widget's places by placing them near other widgets (like some button is under a text view).

This is just a suggestion, maybe there is more than this specific issue and I'm didn't catch the full picture yet.

Here you can read about RealtiveLayout:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

edit: Maximus, great minds think alike, 30 seconds between our comments :)